CSS sliding strip animation
I tried a lot of stuff, but I cannot figure this one out. I want to make a small red line that goes around a box of content indefinitely and stays basically inside the border. However, as the animation progresses, the line starts to change on its way towards the corner and not after. Here is the code:


#main {
  min-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

#main::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: border-slide 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes border-slide {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 2px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    left: 90%;
    width: 2px;
    height: 10%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 90%;
    left: 90%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 2px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 10%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 2px;
  }
}
<div id="main">
  Contents
</div>



I tried different methods, but basically, nothing helped. I just want that red line to go around the main content's box, but I just cannot figure out how.
Edit: I want the line to smoothly go through the edge, curving at the edge. It is very similar to @NINE's answer; it just appears on the right side after it finishes the top side. I want it to transition, curve, and not just appear on the next side, so the line isn't always straight; it has to curve at the edge. I want it to always have the same speed.

If you have any other code besides css, please register for the question together. I recommend posting it as a viable snippet.

Could you clarify exactly what you want it to look like? The code given by @NINE gives a very different result from what you seemed to describe in particular: is the line to maintain the same dimensions at all times? Is the line to go round the edge not diagonally across? Do you want it to smoothly change direction (ie to the first bit goes through a rightangle before the last bit, so it's not always a staight line)? Is it to have constant speed?

What about speed, is it to maintain the same speed whichever side it is on?

Rather than trying to animate a line, or rather a set of lines trying to emulate a curve and going round a corner, CSS can basically do all that for you with a combination of conic gradients, animation and CSS variables.
What 'rotates' is the CSS variable, --border-angle, and the backgrounds use this to work out where to be.


<style>
  .box {
    width: 60vmin;
    height: 50vmin;
    --border-angle: 0turn;
    --main-bg: linear-gradient(white, white);
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-radius: 2em;
    --gradient-border: conic-gradient(from var(--border-angle), transparent 90%, red 90% 100%);
    background: var(--main-bg) padding-box, var(--gradient-border) border-box, var(--main-bg) border-box;
    background-position: center center;
    animation: bg-spin 3s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes bg-spin {
    to {
      --border-angle: 1turn;
    }
  }
  
  @property --border-angle {
    syntax: "<angle>";
    inherits: true;
    initial-value: 0turn;
  }
</style>
<div class="box"></div>



This demo isn't perfect, the line slightly 'shrinks' but it might be a good basis for getting what you want as the curvature is dealt with by CSS.
It is a simplified form of the method used in https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/RwJwJJx which itself says was inspired by the mega buttons on https://turbo.build/
Apologies that I don't have time at the moment to refine the outcome but hope it may point to a more perfect solution.

for some reason this doesnt work for me. the red line isnt moving, its still on the top border eventhough i copied the code exactly. @AHaworth

When you say you copied the code exactly have you made a complete document? In particular <!document html> as the first line? Otherwise the browser will be in quirks mode.

Actually it works for me even in quirks mode so forget that. How are you doing the copying and what browser are you using?
